# iOS: WKWebView Does Not Display SVG

Tags: swift, svg, ios8, uiwebview, wkwebview

I am trying to load a **local** (not served from a server) HTML file that has an embedded SVG in it.  The HTML looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="overflow: hidden">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>icon_people_search</title>
  </head>

  <body style="overflow: hidden; ">
      <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 72 72" xml:space="preserve">

      <path class="st0" d="M46.1,51c-4.9,0-9.5-1.9-12.9-5.4c-3.5-3.5-5.4-8-5.4-12.9s1.9-9.5,5.4-12.9c0.7-0.7,1.5-1.3,2.3-1.9
            c-2.5-3.4-6.6-5.6-11.2-5.6c-7.6,0-13.7,6-13.7,13.4c0,5,2.8,9.5,7,11.8C7.5,40.5,0.2,50,0.2,60h48.1c0-3-0.7-6.1-1.9-8.8
            C46.3,51.2,46.2,51,46.1,51z"/>

      <path class="st0" d="M71.8,52.3L59.5,40c3.2-5.8,2.4-13.3-2.6-18.3c-6-6-15.7-6-21.7,0s-6,15.7,0,21.7c4.9,4.9,12.4,5.8,18.3,2.6
            l12.3,12.3L71.8,52.3z M40.3,38.4c-3.2-3.2-3.2-8.4,0-11.7c3.2-3.2,8.4-3.2,11.7,0c3.2,3.2,3.2,8.4,0,11.7
            C48.8,41.7,43.5,41.7,40.3,38.4z"/>

      </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

The HTML displays correctly in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari on Mac OS X.  It also displays correctly on Android 4 and above's `WebView`.

However, it does **not** display on iOS 8 using a `WKWebView` and Swift. There don't seem to be any errors.  The `WKWebView` just displays as a blank, white box.

Any idea why it's not working, and how I can make it work?  I've seen some examples for iOS where the SVG as embedded using an `<embed>` or `<object>` tag, but I need the SVG to be inline as shown above so that it can be manipulated with JavaScript/jQuery to change fill colors of elements in the SVG.

Any thoughts, ideas, or examples?

Answer (score 0):

Working fine for my in a WKWebView targeting the iOS 9 SDK.  Maybe something is wrong with your string HTML formatting?  Make sure you escape all double quote characters and set your baseUrl.

```
let webview = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
self.view.addSubview(webview)
self.view.bringSubviewToFront(webview)

let html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html style=\"overflow: hidden\"><head><meta charset=\"UTF-8\"><title>icon_people_search</title></head><body style=\"overflow: hidden; \"><svg version=\"1.1\" id=\"Layer_1\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\" x=\"0px\" y=\"0px\" viewBox=\"0 0 72 72\" xml:space=\"preserve\"><path class=\"st0\" d=\"M46.1,51c-4.9,0-9.5-1.9-12.9-5.4c-3.5-3.5-5.4-8-5.4-12.9s1.9-9.5,5.4-12.9c0.7-0.7,1.5-1.3,2.3-1.9c-2.5-3.4-6.6-5.6-11.2-5.6c-7.6,0-13.7,6-13.7,13.4c0,5,2.8,9.5,7,11.8C7.5,40.5,0.2,50,0.2,60h48.1c0-3-0.7-6.1-1.9-8.8C46.3,51.2,46.2,51,46.1,51z\"/><path class=\"st0\" d=\"M71.8,52.3L59.5,40c3.2-5.8,2.4-13.3-2.6-18.3c-6-6-15.7-6-21.7,0s-6,15.7,0,21.7c4.9,4.9,12.4,5.8,18.3,2.6l12.3,12.3L71.8,52.3z M40.3,38.4c-3.2-3.2-3.2-8.4,0-11.7c3.2-3.2,8.4-3.2,11.7,0c3.2,3.2,3.2,8.4,0,11.7C48.8,41.7,43.5,41.7,40.3,38.4z\"/></svg></body></html>"

webview.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleURL)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Does it work if you target iOS 8?  We pasted in the html you're using (in our app, we're reading it from an HTML file on the app) and it still didn't work.  How do you target iOS 9?  I don't see it as an option in XCode; only up to 8.4.

Comment: I'm using Xcode 7 Beta 5.  I will target iOS 8 and get back to you.

Comment: @user3303372 Just tried targeting iOS 8.  Everything appears to be working for me: http://i.stack.imgur.com/e9qfz.png.  Have you used the debugging tools with Safari to see if you're getting any runtime errors?

Comment: JAL How do we use the debugging tools with Safari to debug a WKWebView in an app?  Sorry for the bonehead question, but we're new with iOS development.

Comment: First enable developer tools in Safari, then navigation to Developer -> Simulator (or device) -> YourApp.app.  You should now see the raw HTML and have access to the Javascript console, where any errors would appear. http://i.stack.imgur.com/8Lr9G.png

Comment: Thank you, we've made a bit of progress.  Turns out the SVG is rendered, but we have the WKWebView as small view on the screen, as we want to SVG to be an icon image.  Apparently the SVG isn't scaling to the size of the WKWebView.  How can we size the WKWebView so that the SVG within it scales to the size of the WKWebView?

Comment: Try adding this meta tag to your html: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: Last question:  Can you set the size of the `WKWebView` to be something like 150px by 150px?  If so, how would you do that?  if you do that, does the SVG within scale down?

Comment: You can change the frame of a WKWebView by changing the `frame` property to (0, 0, 150, 150).  Try it and see if the svg scales.